# Why is 毎日 placed before 家 here?

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence, time, help

"妻は毎日家でお茶を飲みます。"

It seems so weird. I was told by a Native that in Japanese, they tend to put words for time at the start of the sentence, so putting it before 妻 makes sense to me. I'm using Lingodeer though, and they often have me put things involving time before the action, like 娘は毎朝牛乳を買います。

So why is it placed before house? The sentence it wants me to translate is "My wife drinks tea at home every day."

I essentially tried to do "妻は家に毎日お茶を飲みます。", but this was labeled wrong. On that note, my understanding of に vs で is that で when referring to to a location is more for a general area where as に is more specific. This is true right? I can see why my sentence was wrong on that count, I just try to second guess what particles it thinks I know, as I'm reviewing the entire course before moving to the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your に and で question, the difference is really that に goes with a certain fixed said of words (いる and synonyms and 住む are the first that come to mind), whereas で is used for the rest. In the past に was used more (that's why gravestones say ここに眠る), but not any more.

As for the adverb, you can really place it wherever you want as long as it's not between a word and partcile. 毎日妻は家でお茶を飲みます, 妻は毎日家でお茶を飲みます, 妻は家で毎日お茶を飲みます, 妻は家でお茶を毎日飲みます, and even 妻は家でお茶を飲みます、毎日 (those this one is kind of conversational) all work. You must have been marked wrong because of the で に.

Comment: In my experience, Lingodeer marks you wrong if you don't place things exactly where they want it. I could be wrong, but this isn't the first sentence I've felt confused about the validity of only to find it's mostly correct. I'll test it out tomorrow though.